# What is the Big-$\Omega$ of $\prod_{i=2}^n \log{(i)}$

Tags: asymptotics

It's similar to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2526586/what-is-the-big-o-of-prod-i-2n-logi) question, but I'm looking for the lower limit.